# Generate one hundred million random integers efficiently

Tags: php, arrays

I want to generate one hundred million integers using PHP, but my code is too slow to run:

```
<?php
$arr=array();
while(count($arr)<10000)
{
  $arr[]=rand(1,10000);
  $arr=array_unique($arr);
}
echo implode(" ",$arr);
?>
```

How may I improve it?

Comment: I can't get it to run, exhausted memory even if I increase the memory_limit, but `$arr = range(1, 100000000);
shuffle($arr);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Came to the same conclusion myself. I tried up to 1,000,000 but more zeroes blew memory. Certainly it did the job in a matter of moments. You should you comment into an answer.

Comment: maybe the number is too ,I edit it,how could i improve it?

Comment: @Manngo: Added some stuff for fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`100,000,000` numbers is very ambitious and not very realistic, however, on my computer (Intel Core i5-3320M 2.6GHz, 8GB Memory, Windows 7 64-bit) with PHP 7.1.3 (supposed to be much better with memory than 5.x), your loop ran for about `8 hours` before I killed it.  With only `10,000` it runs in `1596 seconds`, that's `27 minutes`.

The main problem, aside from the number of iterations, is `array_unique()`.  It takes time on each iteration to run on an ever increasing sometimes huge array and possibly removes an item that then needs to be regenerated.

I tried a better approach by using the number as the key to avoid duplicates.  With a `memory_limit` of `7G` (Much less and it dies with a *Fatal error out of memory*), it ran in `1018 seconds`, that's `17 minutes`. With only `10,000` it runs in `.0035 seconds`:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '7G');

$arr = array();
while(count($arr) < 100000000)
{
  $num = rand(1, 100000000);
  $arr[$num] = $num;
}
```

The following runs in `21 seconds` with a `memory_limit` of `550M` (Much less and it dies with a *Fatal error out of memory*). With only `10,000` it runs in `.0005 seconds` and didn't need memory above my default of `128M`.

Let PHP create a range for you (unique), then shuffle it (randomize).  Now you have all your numbers in a random order with no need to generate them one-by-one, eliminate duplicates and generate more:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '550M');

$arr = range(1, 10000000);
shuffle($arr);
```